# Are Long (1 Minute+) KeepAlives GOOD for a JSON/Ajax WebService?

Tags: linux, apache, nginx, keep-alive, spdy

I know keepalives are great for eliminating the TCP connection penalty when we have lots of rapid-succession requests from a client browser, but what about the case of something like a JSONP web service?  This has different characteristics than a web page load:

1. The client (browser) will typically make 1 request at a time.  Few to no ancillary rapid-fire requests for referenced files like in HTML.
2. The requests will occasionally be in succession, but more usually a few seconds or even minutes apart.  Setting keepalive very low like many advise isn't always a reasonable setting.  Apache's current default is 5s (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#keepalivetimeout), which is lower than 1.3's 15s (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/core.html#keepalivetimeout).  Both are *much* lower than a minute.  This could be because 15 was too high, or broadband mitigated latency -- or both.  The current 5s would probably accomplish nothing good for this scenario.

We can assume we do not hog a Linux task per connection -- a thread or process -- while the socket is left open in idle/WAIT/blocked keepalive state, but would it be a good idea to just leave sockets like that dangling open for a few minutes?  Options to make that happen would be Nginx, Apache Event MPM, etc. that use underlying event based features in *nix like kqueue or epoll.  Assume dynamic content is fulfilled in another task pool and once done, the keepalive'd socket will be just an open file descriptor.

Is it really "just" a file descriptor?  How much does it cost the linux kernel for example to track more of them in an more or less idle state.  Will this cause a webserver to run out of FDs or starve it in any way?  This cost should be weighed against the cost of building up another TCP connection for a subsequent request from scratch.

http://gabenell.blogspot.com/2010/11/connection-keep-alive-timeouts-for.html & http://blog.fastmail.fm/2011/06/28/http-keep-alive-connection-timeouts/ document that everything except Safari will hold it >= 1 minute.  http://www.semicomplete.com/blog/geekery/ssl-latency.html documents TCP latencies for HTTP and HTTPS.

Answer (score 1):

I think one should weigh other things in this situation. It is less likely that keep-alive would burden your sever; it should be at least partially dedicated to the task. More serious bottlenecks are the client and the intermediate elements. The client sometimes has a limit on total connections (browsers tend to have it per page, per server and globally). The most fragile hop along the way is a NAT router. Some of the clients might be behind a NAT that cannot track more than a few thousand connections from sometimes hundreds of users. In this case you might be wasting percents of the available resource to keep the connection open (and have to code against the high possibility of disconnection). Weigh that to the time required: to build a connection (even over HTTPS and with client certificates) should not take long (compared to the idle time) and requires only 3 extra round-trips (worst case should be half a second on a mobile device). Also consider common downsides of keep-alive: clients are prevented from roaming (e.g. switching between mobile data and wifi); resources are marked "in-use" while actually not (e.g. the device or its components are prevented from heeding the power policies set up by the owner). So I would advise against a keep-alive unless one of the following is true: a) the implementation of the keep-alive is somehow much easier than reconnection [I'd be surprised if this wasn't the opposite case], or b) you're in a real-time environment [when RTT becomes relevant, you would want to drop it all together, not just 3 out of 4].

Comment: 1/2 a second is longer than the web service's response time.  I ask mostly because it looks like Chrome is the most aggressive about keepalives -- Google is thinking something.  Modern webservers make it possible to make it just a file handle, and the worst case AFAIK would be the router kills the connection and it falls back to a non-keepalive, unless you could get buggy behavior.

Comment: Right, but half sec only applies to mobile networks will in itself not spoil an 'instantaneous' reaction (other things will); but if it really is a phone, the owner will hate you (quite rightfully) for depleting his battery. And you probably have coded something extra. All this for what? To get an unpercievable 'boost' after seconds (possibly minutes) of fiddling around. So on a desktop the difference would be slim to none, on mobile the user probably cursed you.

Comment: The web+browser infrastructure is not meant for this kind of rape. If your task necessitates a connection waiting then consider creating an application/proxy for mobile devices, since the worst downsides of keepalive show on the mobile+browser (you should react to device sleep/wakeup, connection state change).

Comment: I'd agree with you, but if you look at the way Google is going to SPDY and HTTP2, it's not that way.

Comment: Those are protocols designed to eliminate RTT. And they don't propose any long keepalives, they only keep the connection alive for one download (i.e. the full reaction to an event) and do not wait for another event to happen. In this case the downsides are negligible. As I understand you suggested to keep a connection open for minutes (like expecting an AJAX request) and there the downsides show (and probably that's why this "optimalization" is not addressed in the protocol drafts.

Comment: Then why does Chrome have a 5 minute keepalive by default?  http://blog.fastmail.fm/2011/06/28/http-keep-alive-connection-timeouts/

Comment: Chrome for desktop is not meant for mobile devices. On my Android Chrome closes connections. In the post fastmail chose to ignore mobile devices; you should make that decision based on the task at hand. I don't want to suggest either, just want to highlight the less obvious consequences. Also note how this article explains the problem with dropped NAT-associations (and I really could roll a list of UK WiFi providers where a connection does not stand a chance for even 30s idle).

Comment: (In other words; keepalive is default).  There is no notion of keep-alive in SPDY; the connection is kept as long as both endpoints are willing to keep it.

Comment: ... though keeping 1 connection open is far better than keeping 4 open.  Still, they're going to do this because the handshake on TCP+SSL is far worse than non-SSL.

Comment: Sorry, the first comment were not written with HTTP Connection: Keep-Alive in mind, and mistakenly thought you would use AJAX to force a connection being kept open. What I still maintain is that "far worse" is relative. For a few seconds of download the handshake process is bad allright, so we love persistent connections. The browser HAS TO be smart enough to adjust the timeout according to the device (so it does not kill the phone1's battery).

Comment: No -- I wouldn't force it open.  I'd just let the browser hold it open as long as it wants, which could be _awhile_.  The problems with doing something like this with mod_php or mod_perl, etc. become obvious, though.  Many webservers default at something like 5s or 15s.  Nginx is higher, but still not 5mins.

Comment: Now the benefits of a long timeout (i.e. waiting minutes for an event). You get a negligible speedup on mobile devices that suck on both net & CPU speed anyways (and you sacrifice most of the battery life). You get real speedup on desktops if you can keep both rendering-time and response time inside a few hundred ms; but you still run the risk of dropped NAT making it turn into much worse. I think these were the same considerations webserver/browser developers made about the volatile applications before coming up with their current defaults. I'd only try altering if it is crucial for the task.

Comment: At what point are you pushing it for NAT? I'd think 1-2mins won't get that hiddden penalty when a router simply drops a connection.

Comment: I had firsthand experience in 3 big UK cities with major WiFi broadband providers where droptime was reliably <30s. Also seen some in the 30-60s range. I'm mostly involved in web2 apps, about that field my strong opinion is that after a page loads, the users are for 5-10s in the "rapid fire" mindset (just swifting through for something they know, verifying what they expected to see) and only that long is fast response crucial: accomplish practiced chores fast. Once they begin spending tens of seconds processing, they won't notice even seconds of delay before picking up pace. So I don't bother.

Comment: BTW if I torrent on half of my bandwidth my home router -you can bet I tweak decent ones- takes about 80s to drop associations, but definitely not more than two minutes. These are opinions and experiences I can contribute with; judge for yourself when/if they apply. I also advise to have some reservations with standards: given the amount of terrible mainstream standards that emerged in the last two decades in relation to web technology, I do not take the engineering superiority of any committee granted, especially Google/Facebook/etc.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook uses long polling and resets the connection every 55 seconds regardless if there is a response or not. They overcame the problem of Apache being overloaded by using a comet server in the backend.

The problem with leaving the connection open on the frontend is that most browsers limit the total number of simultaneous connections to the same domain. This could slow down your page loading and even freeze it. For example, if firefox lets me have 2 connections open to a domain and do a 60 second poll, that leaves me with one connection for everything else. If I want to download a large file and a few images, I'd be stuck doing that on my one remaining stream. This is where it would be better to use short polling instead of the long polling technique. Websockets will help this problem though.

Sorry, I can't add comments yet.

https://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=14218138919